# ipad:orientation issues

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Regards to everybody here I am with another problem. I have some screens which basically have several search filters and search results are displayed accordingly in a table. Now I have orientation issues cause this search screen does not cover the full screen in landscape mode.

Solutions that I came across:

1. Two xibs for same view but I'll loose data if I do so as this data will be in bulk so I can store it locally.
2. write lots of coordinate related code which is again cumbersome as there will be lots of search filters.
3. Autoresizemask -> not able to implement this upto expectations. (I tried this but was able to move the screen to the center but I wanted the complete view expanded resizefill something)

Can anybody enlighten me on this  so that screens can be prepared in standard ways.
Thnx in advance.

Refer the screen shots
[image: portrait mode]

[image: landscapemode]

Comment: How do you expect the end result to look? It seems to me that it's entirely possible to resize this view with autoresizing masks.

Comment: I want that in landscape mode also complete screen is populated from left to right as in portrait mode. can this be done using autoresizemask

Comment: Sure, why not? That's what autoresizing masks are for. I suggest you play around with them in IB a little bit.

Comment: it didn,t solved my problem all it did was whole view shifted to center I want it stretched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok it finally worked.. we just have to adjust resizing mask for xibs or set autoresizemasks for the view-- as Ole Begemann mentioned